# quadratic equation plot investigation

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

Let $f(x) =-x^2-4x+18 $ so i plot it like this :

[image]

But my imagination created the following:
$-x^2-4x+18=0 ->
x^2+4x = 18->
x^2+4x-18 = 0$

Which yields the parabola upside down. Where's the mistake I made?

Comment: The error lies in the fact that $-x^2-4x+18 \not =0$ but $-x^2-4x+18 =y$, so when you plot $x^2 +4x−18$, you are plotting $-y$, and in that case the parabola is inverted.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. A parabola is in a "U" shape downward if $a<0$ for a quadratic of the form $ax^2+bx+c$. It is obvious $a>0$ so it should be "U" shape upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points of the graph have two coordinates $(x,y)$ where $y=-x^2-4x+18$.
So, if you take $y'=x^2+4x-18=-y\;$ you find  a graph that is the symmetric of the previous one with respect to the $x$ axis.

For $y=0$ you find, if they exists, the points where the graph intersects the $x$ axis and the abscissas of these points are the solutions of the equation $-x^2-4x+18=0$.
 It is true that these solutions are the same as the solutions of $x^2+4x-18=0$ but this simply means that the points of the two graphs that stay on the $x$ axis are **fixed points** of the symmetry $ (x,y)\rightarrow (x,-y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with your logic is that you are setting the expression to zero when you reverse signs.

Note that the graph of your function was $y=f(x)$. If you reverse signs for $f(x)$, you reverse signs for $y$.

By setting $f(x)=0$ and reversing signs, you have shown that both $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$ have the same $x$-intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

$ y=-x^2-4x+18 $ and $y=x^2+4x-18$ have same roots, but are mirrored from one to the other about the x-axis.